# Apply CSS to PHP loaded HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I have a style set out for a div class, for some html that is loaded from this text file.

content.txt

```
<div class="container">
    <main class="content">
        <strong>Paragraph Title</strong> <br>                                
Lots of text that actually goes here.
    </main><!-- .content -->
</div><!-- .container-->
```

In fact, the text between the `<strong>` tags doesn't look any different that the rest of that text.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#auto-slideshow {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid #333333;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #666;
}

#auto-slideshow img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 32.5%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition:opacity .8s linear;
}

#auto-slideshow img.show {
  opacity:1;
}

.content {
  border-right: solid 1px #999999;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="middle">

    <?php 
      echo file_get_contents( "modules/content.txt" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
    ?>                               

    <?php 
      echo file_get_contents( "modules/leftSidebar.txt" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
    ?> 

    <?php 
      echo file_get_contents( "modules/rightSidebar.txt" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
    ?>

  </div><!-- .middle-->
```

And here is what shows up when I inspect the element

[image: Screenshot of style]

**Update**

I increased the size of the border to crazy amounts (100px) and found that the text is wrapping around what should be the border, but it's still not showing the border.

Comment: this might have to do with the font, font-weight, font-size... try setting a distinct color with `strong{color:red}` if you're unsure

Comment: You can also inspect the element (in most modern browsers) to check whether it's getting any styling from your CSS.

Comment: @Calimero I've tried that, too, just didn't post that code in here. I also made the size of the border 100 pixels, still nothing.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel It does say that it's there, but visually it's not.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? When you say `it does say that it's there` what do you mean? Does the inspector show the `.content` selector when you select that element?

Comment: how do you integrate the CSS code ? link element, style element ? please paste that tag code.

Comment: Where is the PHP being echoed? Is it inside a (for some reason I want to put 'an') HTML tag? Also, check you content type. Is it being parsed as HTML?

Comment: Give me a minute, and I will update to answer everyone's questions.

Comment: Okay, edits have been made to the question to include more code and a screenshot of what the element inspector shows. @Aeolingamenfel, if you feel like you would need more of the style then I will grab another shot, but I think this shows all the important stuff.

Comment: I blame `menu.css`. It almost hid from me in that screenshot, but it's there, and it applies a `*` selector, which is usually not a good idea. At any rate, even if that's not it, keep scrolling down in that window until you see something that affects a `font/font-???` property

Comment: @Katana314 Nice catch. Unfortunately it still didn't work.

Comment: @CodyHarness I'm confused..."that didn't work" isn't an answer to the question that was asked: When you scroll down in that view, does anything modify a font-etc property at all? You can ignore entries that are from "user-agent etc"

Comment: @Katana314 I'm sorry, removing the part with the * is what didn't work. I found `font-size: 100%; font: inherit;`

Comment: @CodyHarness So next step: Open the code file that has that entry. Use SVN to find out who added that rule. Walk to their desk, and slam a big ol' cream pie right in their face. (But yes: That rule is your problem. `font: inherit` means "completely imitate the font of the element containing this one in all ways")

Comment: @Katana314 While that definitely solves the problem with the bold text, I still don't have my border, which is also pretty important.